# How can I tell where my XCode output originates from?

Tags: xcode

For example, in my console, I have output such as :

```
2012-11-29 21:25:40.696 Program[31053:707] -[Staff Shifts]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107d6fdd0
2012-11-29 21:25:40.697 Program[31053:707] Exception detected while handling key input.
```

I was wondering if there's an easy way to find out where this is from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug console can only tell you so much. According to the error, you are trying to access a selector (possibly) within the class `Staff` that isn't recognized by the instance of that class.

You could, however, use this bit of information to set a breakpoint within that class and step over methods until the exception reoccurs.  Then you could set a breakpoint at that method and step into it until you find the problem.

You could also use `gdb po` at runtime to check for nil/unexpected objects.

Answer (score 0):

The `[Staff Shifts]` might indicate that you have a class named `[Staff Shifts]` in your code that is causing the error. An `unrecognized selector` means that you have the following:

```
selector: @selector(FunctionName:)
```

But the function `FunctionName:` doesn't exist...